# cant redirect on change event datalist input

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to redirect to a new page with data from the datalist input after a event
(selecting a option) but for some reason its just reloading the page

here is the code I have (I am retrieving the data for the input options with php from a mysql database I don't know if this matters)

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'fetch_data.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        // Populate the datalist input with the data
        var datalist = $('#datalist-input');
        $.each(data, function(key, item) {
            datalist.append('<option data-id="' + item.id + '" value="' + item.name + '">' + item.value + '</option>');
        });

        // Handle the change event on the datalist input
        datalist.change(function() {
          // Retrieve the selected option's ID
          var selectedOption = datalist.find('option:selected');
          var id = selectedOption.data('id');

           // Construct the URL of the target page
           var targetUrl = 'target_page.php?id=' + id;

             // Navigate to the target page
             window.location = targetUrl;
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: ___not working___ Not a really useful description. Please be more specific

Comment: I doubt this fires any change event on the datalist element to begin with, or that you could actually match anything in there with `datalist.find('option:selected')`. You should work with a change or input handler on the actual text field this datalist is _for_.

Comment: You have added change event inside document ready function?, change event occurs when you selects or change the input or type inside the datalist input. Try moving change event outside of document ready function. (Create separate change event for datalist outside document ready function)